# Proper way to pop to another ViewController from a TableViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I have a `TableView` with custom cells that dynamically load and I have attached a `GestureRecognizer` to an `ImageView` so that when you hold down on the `ImageView` and `ActionSheet` appears with an option that allows the user to send a private message. I have the `ViewController` already created for sending the message, I just need to know how to pop to it since the class `UITableViewCell` doesn't include `storyboard` or `navigation controller`. Someone advised me to call a method from the `TableViewController` but I don't have one implemented. Someone please advise. Thanks.

Comment: You need to present it from the controller that is your table view's data source (it doesn't need to be a UITableViewController).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to be called from the root `View Controller` by `UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)`